# Why Qt's addWidget() can accept 1 argument case?

Tags: qt

```
   statusBar()->addWidget(locationLabel);
   statusBar()->addWidget(formulaLabel, 1);
```

Above code is from a Qt program.
And below description is from Qt help when I pressed F1 on `addWidget`.
As you can see, `addWidget` shall accept 2 arguments. My question is why above 1st sentence can be executed normally?

> void QStatusBar::addWidget ( QWidget * widget, int stretch = 0 ) 
>   Adds the given widget to this status bar, reparenting the widget if it
>   isn't already a child of this QStatusBar object. The stretch parameter
>   is used to compute a suitable size for the given widget as the status
>   bar grows and shrinks. The default stretch factor is 0, i.e giving the
>   widget a minimum of space.
>
> The widget is located to the far left of the first permanent widget
>   (see addPermanentWidget()) and may be obscured by temporary messages.

Comment: It has a default argument - the first call is receiving two arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because C++ has the concept of `default argument`s, which means that a function declared as

```
void f(int i, int j=1);
```

can be called by

```
f(42);
```

and

```
f(42,43);
```

In the first case, the function call is equivalent to

```
f(42,1);
```

In your case,

```
addWidget(label);
```

is equivalent to

```
addWidget(label,0);
```